# How to get value from n-dimensional array - (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, logic

I want to get a String value of multi-dimensional array
and push it into a new Array (That'd be an answer!)

For Example :

```
var dimStr = [ "First-one", ["Double-one", "Double-two", "Double-three", 
["Triple-one", "Triple-two"] ], "First-two" ] ;
```

And the output should be :

```
output = ["First-one", "Double-one", "Double-two", "Double-three", "Triple-one", 
    "Triple-two", "First-two" ] ;
```

Thank you very much in advance for your kindness.

The output should be a new Array that contains every String value from dimStr

Comment: Have you looked at the `.flat()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the array method [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```
output = dimStr.flat(3);
```